# Apple Watch Simulator Won't Start

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I can not get any apple watch simulators to run, so finally I tried doing absolutely nothing and even with "default settings" the watch simulator won't run.

File --> New -- Project --> Single View Application --> Name = WTF --> Next --> Create --> File --> New --> Target --> Apple Watch --> Watchkit App --> Next --> Uncheck Include Notification Scene --> Finish --> Activate --> Build and Run WTF Watchkit App on iPhone 6...

NO WATCH SIMULATOR.

I'm using XCode 6.3.1. What do I need to do to make up for Apple on this issue?

I've tried... deleting and recreating the scheme; various iPhone simulator devices; deleting app from simulator, reseting simulator, cleaning project... messing around with wrapper extensions...

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are running the simulator go to Hardware -> External displays and chose the Apple watch size you want to simulate. This should show another window.